# Php format numbers in a string with regexp

Tags: php, regex

I need help with writing a regular expression in PHP. I am not friend enough to get it right. I need to find all integers in a string and format them as follows:

```
1 to 001000
0.13 to 000130
100 to 0100000
```

and so on. In normal speech it means - edit the number prepend it with zeros or edit it to be in same "order". The point is to have all of the integers it the string in this  format (6 numbers). Could someone help me please? I will not post my tryouts here because they are too foolish:-)

Comment: Your last example has `7` digits.

Comment: Could there be negative numbers? If so, what should happen with them? Could there be decimal numbers without a leading zero like `.13`?

Comment: No to all. There can be only positive values with leading zeros. I get the input from XML file which contains only values as 13 or 20 or 186.578962453. I need to strip the values  and make it exactly 6 digits. It will be yoused for searching purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using the '`e`' modifier on [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) (or using [`preg_replace_callback()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php)) you can use @codaddict's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3904489/php-format-numbers-in-a-string-with-regexp/3904498#3904498):

```
function my_format($d) {
    return sprintf('%06d', round($d * 1000));
}

$your_string = '0.12 100 number 1.12 something';

preg_replace('/\d+(\.\d+)?/e', 'my_format(\\0)', $your_string);
// Should give '000120 100000 number 001120 something'
```

Comment: @codaddict Right. I should have copy-pasted your code instead :)

Comment: Thanks guys for quick responses. I'll give it a try and let you know:-)

Comment: I tryied proposed solution - there should be *round($d...*. Unless I am guessing something wrong - i need to change ALL of the numeric values including 1.12 in @jengram's example. And also when I tested it - it strips the space after the number. What I need is to let the rest of the string intact. The purpose of this code is to process Zend Lucene query in order to be capable searching float point numbers.... :-) I know I am being...iritating :-D

Comment: @Bery Yes, the `round()` was a(nother) typo. About the `1.12` I misread your comment. I have (hopefully) fixed it now.

Answer (score 2):

From your examples looks like you are multiplying the number with `1000` and prefixing them with `0`'s to make a total of `6` digits. If that is true you can just do:

```
sprintf("%06d",$n*1000);
```

Comment: It is not exactly multiplying. I need to have all numbers to have exactly the same lenght. The range is "000.000" to "999.999". And for every number in the input string i need an output which looks like "xxxxxx". Exactly six digits (with prepending zeros) without a point.