# PHP - preg_replace number within string

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I am working with a string like:

```
$string = "2017 MODEL YEAR 6.7L POWER STROKE V8 DIESEL 6-SPEED AUTO TRANS 3.55 ELECTRONIC LOCKING AXLE FX4 OFF-ROAD PACKAGE .SKID PLATES 10000-lb. GVWR PACKAGE";
```

Within the string is the string `10000-lb. GVWR PACKAGE`. My goal is to apply `number_format` to 10000 so that the string reads `10,000-lb. GVWR PACKAGE`.

I have been testing with `preg_replace` and can get to the number using:

```
preg_replace('!\d+-lb\.!', '\0', $string);
```

I attempt to apply `number_format` like:

```
preg_replace('!\d+-lb\.!', number_format('\0'), $string);
```

but receive the following error:

```
number_format() expects parameter 1 to be float, string given
```

Applying `intval()` to the match returns a 0 and not the expected 10,000.

I am not sure how to proceed. The catch I have also identified is that I do not want number formatting applied to the first 2017. Do I need to adjust the `preg_match` to not be as specific or perhaps apply a `preg_match` to the match within the first `preg_match` to get the number only?

Comment: Odd that floatval returns the way it does. What kind of variations are there on "10000" can it be "8000"?

Comment: You can use this answer: [Php format numebrs in a string with regexp](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3904536/3600709)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to go around it is to match two separate \d's.
First one is one or more digits, second one is exactly three digits.

Then I use str_replace to replace the number in the string.

```
$string = "2017 MODEL YEAR 6.7L POWER STROKE V8 DIESEL 6-SPEED AUTO TRANS 3.55 ELECTRONIC LOCKING AXLE FX4 OFF-ROAD PACKAGE .SKID PLATES 10000-lb. GVWR PACKAGE";

Preg_match("/(\d+)(\d{3})-lb/", $string, $match);

$find = $match[0];
$replace = $match[1] .",". $match[2] ."-lb";

Echo str_replace($find, $replace, $string);
```

https://3v4l.org/HvAjg
This will work for numbers 1000+, if you need numbers below 1000 then it needs some tweaks. Just tell me and I will fix it.